# Check if string contains a combination of words excluding certain words with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex filter to detect if a string contains a certain substring without certain words.

For example, I want to find all the strings that contain a substring "account manager" and exclude all managers, senior managers and senior account managers

I have tried to use the re.findall(r"account|manager") and then check if the length of the array is 2 and the array doesn't contain words senior or sr.

Instead of this, I would like to create an expression to (exclude words senior and sr) and (include words account and manager)
so the condition should return True/False condition values for the following examples:

```
sr manager - False
senior key account manager - False
sr. key account manager - False
account manager - True
key account manager - True
manager - False
account manager - True
```

I tried to create something like the following, which is incorrect:
(?!senior|sr)(key|account|manager)

Does anyone know what is the right way to check for such condition?

Comment: Find the strings that contain "account manager." Find the strings that contain the words that you do not want. Take the set difference.

Comment: this was just an example that might not illustrate the best the question I was asking - check for words, not necessarily subsequent and exclude certain words

Comment: @NikoGamulin, you can try [`^(?:(?!sr\.|senior).)*account\s+manager`](https://regex101.com/r/zjNSKL/2)

Comment: You may try: `^(?!.*\b(?:sr\.?|senior)\s.*\bmanager\b).*\baccount\s+manager\b`

Comment: @NikoGamulin I was typing up a long answer but unfortunately this was closed (why?!). My suggestion is to use the `regex` module in python which allows variable-width lookbehinds, and you can do something like: `(?<!((?:(?:senior)|(?:sr))).*)account manager`, link here: https://regex101.com/r/aKK8P4/1/, screenshot here: https://gyazo.com/af6f7420e4be098d898bb22d889b6521

Comment: Closed because it is a dupe. This is a common question, match a string containing one pattern but not another. `^(?!.*(?:sr\.|senior)).*account\s+manager`. Or, `^(?!.*\b(?:sr\.|senior\b)).*\baccount\s+manager\b`

Answer (score 2):

Relying on regex for a simple task is generally a poor idea. Here's a simple, easy-to-read function that passes all your test cases.

```py
from typing import List
def validate_str(s: str, target_substring: str, excluded_strs: List[str]) -> bool:
    if target_substring not in s:
        return False
    if any((i in s for i in excluded_strs)):
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: while your statement is not incorrect it does not seem to address the OP's question ... and if their dataset is large this might be significantly slower

Comment: Well, his question was "Does anyone know what is the right way to check for such condition?", and I answered that.

Comment: fair point :) ...

Comment: I modified the title. I already implemented the logic without regex